# Angular 5 best way to to show components based on configuration

Tags: angular, components

In my application, I have dashboard component. In the dashboard component OnInit, I call a service that return me a configuration with 3 possible usecases.

Basically the answer is something like that :

```
{
  "usecase": "usecase1" // "usecase2" or "usecase3"
}
```

For each usecase, the whole dashboard content will not be the same.

I have 3 components for each usecase : useCase1Component, useCase2Component, useCase3Component

I want to know the best way to show/render the right component based on the usecase.

I could maybe do this using *ngIf like this in the dashboardComponent html :

```
<useCase1Component *ngIf="showUseCase1"></useCase1Component>
<useCase2Component *ngIf="showUseCase2"></useCase2Component>
<useCase3Component *ngIf="showUseCase3"></useCase3Component>
```

But I'm not sure it's the best way, and I don't see how I could achieve this in another way with good performance.

Comment: [Dynamic components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) is made for that. **RTFM** !

Comment: Using dynamic component loading isn't always the best way to go, in specific scenarios it won't work at all. Such as having to apply directives to a component for instance. I would use *ngIf or *ngSwitch in your case.

Comment: Exactly @Chrillewoodz, I've already saw dynamic components and I was not convinced that it works well in my scenario. Moreover, ngIf/ngSwitch would work but is it the best way to go in term of practicies and performance ?

Comment: @ImadElHitti Ye it's completely fine to use it. I'm using it as well and my scenario is way bigger than yours, trust me. I've got massive configs that can be endless so I'm recursively rendering components based on this solution. I even had to switch from the dynamic component way since it didn't allow me to do what I needed.

Comment: Ok sir, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *ngIf. That is [Angulars](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) way of showing or hiding items. Performance is excelent, and you have nothing to worry about it.